# Sending Large CSV to Kafka using python Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-kafka, pyspark, kafka-python

I am trying to send a large CSV to kafka. The basic structure is to read a line of the CSV and zip it with the header.

```
a = dict(zip(header, line.split(",")
```

This then gets converted to a json with:

```
message = json.dumps(a)
```

I then use kafka-python library to send the message

```
from kafka import SimpleProducer, KafkaClient
kafka = KafkaClient("localhost:9092")
producer = SimpleProducer(kafka)
producer.send_messages("topic", message)
```

Using PYSPARK 
I have easily created an RDD of messages from the CSV file

```
sc = SparkContext()
text = sc.textFile("file.csv")
header = text.first().split(',')
def remove_header(itr_index, itr):
    return iter(list(itr)[1:]) if itr_index == 0 else itr
noHeader = text.mapPartitionsWithIndex(remove_header)

messageRDD = noHeader.map(lambda x: json.dumps(dict(zip(header, x.split(","))
```

Now I want to send these messages: I define a function

```
def sendkafka(message):
  kafka = KafkaClient("localhost:9092")
  producer = SimpleProducer(kafka)
  return producer.send_messages('topic',message)
```

Then I create a new RDD to send the messages

```
sentRDD = messageRDD.map(lambda x: kafkasend(x))
```

I then call sentRDD.count()

Which starts churning and sending messages

Unfortunately this is very slow. It sends 1000 messages a second. This is on a 10 node cluster of 4 cpus each and 8gb of memory.

In comparison, creating the messages takes about 7 seconds on a 10 million row csv. ~ about 2gb

I think the issue is that I am instantiating a kafka producer inside the function. However, if I don't then spark complains that the producer doesn't exist even though I have tried defining it globally.

Perhaps someone can shed some light on how this problem may be approached.

Thank you,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a single producer per partition and use either `mapPartitions` or `foreachPartition`:

```
def sendkafka(messages):
    kafka = KafkaClient("localhost:9092")
    producer = SimpleProducer(kafka)
    for message in messages:
        yield producer.send_messages('topic', message)

sentRDD = messageRDD.mapPartitions(sendkafka)
```

If above alone won't help you can try to extend it using an [asynchronous producer](http://kafka-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#asynchronous-mode).

In Spark 2.x it is also possible to use Kafka data source. You'll have to include `spark-sql-kafka` jar, matching Spark and Scala version (here 2.2.0 and 2.11 respectively):

```
spark.jars.packages  org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.2.0
```

convert data to a `DataFrame` (if it is not `DataFrame` already):

```
messageDF = spark.createDataFrame(messageRDD, "string")
```

and write using `DataFrameWriter`:

```
(messageDF.write
    .format("kafka")
    .option("topic", topic_name)
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrap_servers)
    .save())
```

Comment: Thanks zero323. with a single producer outside of spark using a async I could get 8000 per second. So I did some tweaking. I discovered I had 15 partitions for this csv so I gave the job 15 cores. I then played with the async options until the batch size was 20000. That gave me a maximum throughput of 225 thousand a second. So with some tuning I actually got a reasonable rate. That is 45 seconds to stream a 10 million row csv.

Comment: @PhineasDashevsky, it would be very helpful if you could share the code for your final solution.

Comment: https://iabdb.me/2015/09/09/kafka-on-the-shore-my-experiences-benchmarking-apache-kafka-part-i/

In this arcticle I have the code and a longer description of how to do it.

Comment: I try to do this and get NameError: global name 'KafkaClient' is not defined. I think it cannot recognize the kafkaclient within foreachpartition. Anyone had the same problem.